# Flutter run: No supported devices connected error on Mac

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I cannot seem to run my flutter project anymore. I created a new empty one and still the same: I get the same error

No supported devices connected.
The following devices were found, but are not supported by this project:
Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 88.0.4324.192
If you would like your app to run on web, consider running `flutter create .` to
generate projects for these platforms.

It worked perfectly before! I used fluter doctor to check if everything is ok

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on macOS 11.2.2 20D80 darwin-arm, locale
en-GB)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
✗ Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor
  --android-licenses
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS
  development.
  Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
  Or install Xcode via the App Store.
  Once installed, run:
    sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

I run my projects in VSCode and worked perfectly fine before... Flutter is put to date.

When I do flutterdeviced the IOS Simulator does not appear anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Accept licenses and try again. May be they changed agreement
run: `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: Hi, I did this but the problems not for the android emulator though. I think the problems that flutter cannot see the IOS Simulator anymore

Comment: Have yyou tried suggested `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch`?

Comment: yes I did and this is what I GET xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'

Answer (score 0):

export PATH="$PATH://Users/USERNAME/dev/flutter/bin"

```
USERNAME= which user

dev = where flutter is
```

flutter doctor --android-licenses

Comment: Since your answer might solve the problem, please add some explanation about what it does rather than just throwing some codes.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed my issue by running my app first from Xcode then back to android studio: flutter run --release.  worked for me.